# How to connect to a remote MySQL database using Java?

Tags: java, mysql

Can anyone provide me the Java SE coding to connect to the MySQL database in a Server (not in the localhost)? what should I put instead of "localhost" and port number?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    String driverName = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
    Class.forName(driverName);

    String serverName = "localhost";
    String mydatabase = "mydatabase";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql :// " + serverName + "/" + mydatabase; 

    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
  }
}
```

Comment: **What error do you get?** If you are able to connect it on local computer then just replace `localhost` or your ip address in connection string with the ip address or domain name of remote computer where you want to connect. In your code replace `localhost` as a value of `serverName` with ip of remote machine. Also username/password you are using should be valid on remote machine's mySql

Comment: are there any coding to find the server ip address in java

Comment: Why do you need to *find* a server IP address? Are you not supposed to know that beforehand?

Comment: Your `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` driver is **obsolete**, use the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` driver from now on. Also, just change your `serverName` to your server IP address. That's it! :-)

Comment: Thank you @The Elite Gentleman

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply use

```
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://your.database.domain/yourDBname";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

make sure that tou have access right to remote machine in mysql

give ip instead your.database.domain

Comment: yes, but you need to change dburl and driver. i.e string in Class.forName